# Difference of Google Map to Location Based Augmented Reality

Tags: augmented-reality

I want to know what is the difference of google map to location based augmented reality. I want to create a location information using augmented reality in android which is when u point the camera in a particular building you can see a 3d information and the distance of the building to the user. Is it good to create that app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open Google maps you will see all the location on map on your phone you dont add any virtual objects to the world around you but in location based augmented reality applications throught your GPS the application can know where you are and then you can use mobile camera and see virtual 3D objects or text like this wikitude application take a look at it from here
http://www.wikitude.com/showcase/wikitude-navigation/